# Editing Incorrect Information in Questions

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

> Edit: This question is specifically *not* related to code. I'm aware
>   of the precedent on fixing code mistakes. As there did not seem to be
>   any established precedent for issues not related to coding, I asked
>   the question. I don't believe this to be a duplicate, given the
>   specific nature of the question. However, I suppose moderation is a
>   (rather lazy) method of answering the question.

In a question, the asker presented information worded such to establish their existing knowledge on a matter in which formed the foundation of their question. However, their knowledge was not exhaustive on the topic. This inexhaustive knowledge seemed to have led to an incorrect conclusion which prompted the question *(their actual intent still seems rather ambiguous)*.

A user then edited the question, changing this to include a more prominent item. However, had the OP been aware of this item they would likely not have come to the incorrect conclusion and would thus seem to invalidate the question.

I rolled back the question, as I believed information that contradicts the question in such a way to resolve it is functionally an answer to the question, and that editing such information into the question itself can not be done without either changing the intent of the question or invalidating it all together. However, a far more experienced user in our beta stated that the question *needed* (their emphasis) to be edited, as it contained factually inaccurate information.

Was I wrong to rollback this edit?

Comment: This is indeed the proper action - such edit is invalid and should be rolled back.

Comment: I only ever hang out on non-computer-based sites... So I'll tell you what we do... If there's a factual error in the question... you comment on it... Or if the comment would be too long, you make an answer that addresses the fact the question was formed on a false premise and explain the facts. If the OP is wrong about something, **that is part of their question**. Fixing the question doesn't help the OP at all.